# command line interpreter with multiple commands per line

Tags: c, shell, command, line, interpreter

I want to write a comamnd line intepreter with multiple commands per line.

I wrote a program in C which works for 1 comamnd per line but if i enter more commands dont work,comamnds are enter like: ls -l ; pwd ; cat file ; ls.

First i parse args,i put them into array and the i have this function:

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();    

switch(pid) {
    case -1:  
      printf("DEBUG:Fork Failure\n");
      exit(-1);
    case  0:
      execvp(cmd[j], cmd);

      if(execvp(cmd[j], cmd) == -1) {
            printf("Command Not Found\n");
            exit(0);
      }

    default:  
    wait(NULL);
    printf("DEBUG:Child Finished\n");
}
```

My parser is :

```
printf("shell> ");

fgets (input, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

if ((strlen(input)>0) && (input[strlen (input) - 1] == '\n')) {
    input[strlen (input) - 1] = '\0';
}


printf("INPUT: %s\n", input);

cnd = strtok(input, " ;");

int i = 0;

while(cnd != NULL) {    
    cmd[i] = cnd;
    i++;
    cnd = strtok(NULL, ";");
```

I think that i must use pipes to solve my problem,but how ?
Any ideas?

sorry for bad English

Comment: If one commands is parsed correctly, but multiple ones don't, there is a problem with your parser. You don't show your parser...

Answer (score 0):

The way you explain it, it seems to be that you want to execute the commands one after the other, but not have them communicate with each other (besides, piping the output of `ls` to `pwd` just makes no sense).

For that the solution is simple: Split the input on the semicolon, and handle each command as it was a single command (since that's what it is).

With some pseudo-code it could look something like this

```
input = read_next_line();
while ((next_command = get_next_command(input)) != NULL)
{
    execute_command(next_command);
}
```

You could implement this with e.g. `strtok` or similar functions.

Comment: i did it.. i  split the input and put it into array,and i check that the array is correct .
When i try to execute commands i see "command not found"